# How to configure robots.txt to allow everything?

Tags: robots.txt

My `robots.txt` in Google Webmaster Tools shows the following values:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

What does it mean? I don't have enough knowledge about it, so looking for your help. I want to allow all robots to crawl my website, is this the right configuration?

Comment: Allow is not understood by all web crawlers, use disavow: (i.e., with no url after the : ) instead. It is safer (see: https://youtu.be/G29Zt-UH_Ko)

Comment: See also on Webmasters: [What is a minimum valid robots.txt file?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56720/what-is-a-minimum-valid-robots-txt-file)

Answer (score 204):

That file will allow all crawlers access

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

This basically allows all user agents (the *) to all parts of the site (the /).

Comment: Correct, unless you need to negate the allow part. There is not "allow" so make that:

"User-agent: *
Disallow:"

like they show here: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: There is an allow part. Check official Google docs https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#allow

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because `Allow:` is a non-standard addition to the robots.txt.  The original standard only has `Disallow:` directives.  This answer will work for Googlebot and some other search engines, but it isn't universal.  The universal way is to disallow nothing as stated in [Unor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467157/).

Answer (score 126):

If you want to allow every bot to crawl everything, this is the best way to specify it in your robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Note that the `Disallow` field has an empty value, which means [according to the specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format):

> Any empty value, indicates that all URLs can be retrieved.

---

Your way (with `Allow: /` instead of `Disallow:`) works, too, but `Allow` is not part of the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), so it’s not supported by all bots (many popular ones support it, though, [like the Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en)). That said, unrecognized fields have to be ignored, and for bots that don’t recognize `Allow`, the result would be the same in this case anyway: if nothing is forbidden to be crawled (with `Disallow`), everything is allowed to be crawled.
However, formally (per the original spec) it’s an invalid record, because at least one `Disallow` field is required:

> At least one Disallow field needs to be present in a record.

Answer (score 29):

I understand that this is fairly old question and has some pretty good answers. But, here is my two cents for the sake of completeness.

As per the official [documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), there are four ways, you can allow complete access for robots to access your site.

### Clean:

Specify a global matcher with a disallow segment as mentioned by @unor. So your `/robots.txt` looks like this.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

### The hack:

Create a `/robots.txt` file with no content in it. Which will default to allow all for all type of `Bots`.

### I don't care way:

Do not create a `/robots.txt` altogether. Which should yield the exact same results as the above two.

### The ugly:

From the [robots documentation for meta tags](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/noindex.html), You can use the following meta tag on all your pages on your site to let the `Bots` know that these pages are not supposed to be indexed.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
```

In order for this to be applied to your entire site, You will have to add this meta tag for all of your pages. And this tag should strictly be placed under your `HEAD` tag of the page. More about this meta tag [here](https://www.metatags.org/meta_name_robots).

Comment: No robots.txt and Wordpress is a bad combo though, because WordPress generates a virtual robots.txt. Unless you're happy with the one WordPress generates.

Comment: What about TYPO3? It has sitemap by default?

Comment: How is that I didn't create any robots.txt file and still get "Indexed, but blocked by a robots.txt file"?

Comment: do you have the website URL?.

Answer (score 9):

It means you allow every (`*`) user-agent/crawler to access the root (`/`) of your site. You're okay.

Comment: there is no "Allow" field, according to http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html so I'd be careful to use that. Wikipedia mentions "Some major crawlers support an Allow directive which can counteract a following Disallow directive.": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive

Answer (score -3):

I think you are good, you're allowing all pages to crawling
User-agent: *
allow:/

Comment: This answer says nothing that other answers haven't already addressed.