# Want to understand Robots.txt

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

I would like to scrape a website. However I want to make sense of the robots.txt before I do.
The  lines that I don't understand are

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/
Disallow: /*?&*&*
Disallow: /*?*&*
Disallow: /*|*
```

Does the User Agent Line mean access is ok anywhere? But then I have the Disallow line which is the main one I am concerned about. Does it mean don't access 8 layers deep, or don't access at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure robots.txt to allow everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276957/how-to-configure-robots-txt-to-allow-everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one simply interpret the `robot.txt` file with `regex`. The star can usually be interpreted as *anything/everything*.

The User-Agent line `User-agent: *` does not mean you are allowed to scrape everything, it simply means *the following rules apply to all user-agents*. Here are examples of User-Agents

```
# Chrome Browser
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
# Python requests default
python-requests/2.19.1
```

which must comply with the same rules, that is:

- For example `Disallow: /*?*&*` means you are *not allowed* to scrape sub-domains of the form `/some_sub_domain?param_name=param_value`.
- Or the line `/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/` means the sub-domains of the following form are not allowed to be scraped `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/i/`

Finally, [here are insightful examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Examples) and more on the topic.

Comment: Great - so the multi layer is not a catchall but rather relates to a specific form of address?